# Using callbacks on the database to trigger streaming controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and working within an app that has already been written (using Ruby 2.2.3, Rails 4.2.5.1 and Puma 2.16.0). What we want to do is use ActiveRecord Callbacks watching changes in the db (we're calling after_create, after_update) to trigger a streaming controller (something like the examples here: https://www.sitepoint.com/streaming-with-rails-4/) to send a message using data from the model. We already have the callbacks written within the specific model class.

e.g.

```
after_create do 

  require 'json'
  tempHash = {
    "event_type" => "some event type",
    "data" => {
      "id" => "#{id}",
      "name" => "#{name}",
    }
  }

end
```

The data in tempHash is what would go in the message we want to send.

How could we trigger a messaging controller to send this data? Or is there a better way to do this within Ruby on Rails?

Comment: This certainly does not belong in the model. Is there a reason why this would not be placed in the Controller that is handling `create` and `update` routing for the object? Otherwise can you explain the use case a bit more as it is a bit unclear what your actual intentions are here.

Comment: Model is not supposed to do this. This use case has nothing to to with streaming?

Comment: [This Link](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/adding-a-realtime-module-to-your-rails-api-18bb562e6441) is probably close to what you want.

Another thing to note, the active record callbacks aren't actually on the Database, but on the Model.  Changing the DB through rails will get caught. but if the database is manually updated from some other source, or directly it will not.

Comment: The db doesn't get modified in the model, rather the it gets populated and updated using catalog::abstractadapter to get data from an outside xml file using open-uri and nokogiri. Would there be a better way to watch for changes in the database than open record callbacks? Can you do that from a controller?

Basically we want to be able to send a notification when data in a section of the db is updated or created

Comment: best bet is probably something like a combination of [`hair_trigger`](https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger) and [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever). Use `hair_trigger` to create SQL triggers to watch changes and use `whenever` to check the changes table regularly for new events. Not exactly "Live" but may be close enough

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade your rails version to 5? `ActionCable` could help you a lot with your issue.